# Windsor Performance Counter miss in PerfMon

Tags: castle-windsor, performancecounter, performance-monitor

I would like to add the performance counter of windsor in my Performance Monitor... 
I have configured Windsor as indicated in the [docs](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/performance-counters.md) :

```
var diagnostic = LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy.GetTrackedComponentsDiagnostic(container.Kernel);
var counter = LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy.GetTrackedComponentsPerformanceCounter(new PerformanceMetricsFactory());
container.Kernel.ReleasePolicy = new LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy(diagnostic, counter);
```

Then I run my Web Api application, and I run the performance Monitor. But when I try to add a new counter I do not find the "Castle Windsor" section.
[image]

What's wrong in what am  I doing?

PS.: I am using windsor 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely Windsor doesn't have permission to create the performance counter category and counter (i.e. write to the registry) and is swallowing the `SecurityException` in `PerformanceMetricsFactory.Initialize`.

Run your application or Visual Studio elevated as administrator, you will only need to do this once.